# Two-line ListView does not show content

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listadapter

I currently have a problem with my two-line ListView. The two-line ListView shows the list separator, however, there is no data or text inside it. Where could I possibly have done wrong?

For additional information, the `results.get(i)` will show `Tungro,18.92%`, for example.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> listItemData;

    for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++) {

        if (results.size() != 0) {
            listItemData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String resultStr = results.get(i).toString();
            String[] resultStrVar = resultStr.split(",");

            listItemData.put(resultStrVar[0], resultStrVar[1]);
            listItems.add(listItemData);

        } else {
            listItemData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            listItemData.put("No predictions found", "Kindly shot again");
            listItems.add(listItemData);
        }
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Results.this, listItems,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[] {"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Below is the screenshot of the ListView, where you could see the list separator but without text or data:

[image]

Is there something wrong with how I tokenize the string or with the adapter? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `String[]` array that you pass as the fourth argument in the `SimpleAdapter` constructor call are the keys for the item `Map` that you're giving to the `SimpleAdapter`. That is, for each `Map` item you've given `SimpleAdapter`, there must be values in each `Map` corresponding to the keys in that array. You've passed `"First Line"` and `"Second Line"` which do not correspond to any of the keys you've used in putting values into each item's `Map`; currently, `resultStrVar[0]` in the `if` block, and `"No predictions found"` in the `else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike M! I have changed my code to the following:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> listItemData;

for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++) {

    if (results.size() != 0) {
        listItemData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String resultStr = results.get(i).toString();
        String[] resultStrVar = resultStr.split(",");

        listItemData.put("disease_name", resultStrVar[0]);
        listItemData.put("confidence", resultStrVar[1]);
        listItems.add(listItemData);

    } else {
        listItemData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        listItemData.put("disease_name", "No predictions found");
        listItemData.put("confidence", "Kindly shot again");
        listItems.add(listItemData);
    }
}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Results.this, listItems,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        new String[] {"disease_name", "confidence"},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```